# Visual Studio: Django template with DTL. Problem: HTML form tag doesn't accept DTL(Django Template Language) tag with double (")

Tags: django, django-templates

My problem is when I write the  HTML tag with the DTL(*Django Template Language*) tag for URL, VSC mark it as wrong (the reason is obvious: wrong string detecting).

[image]

I'm not entirely sure what approach is the most proper. Should I use an escape character for the inner `"` or write this?:
[image]

If an escape character is the most proper way how should be constructed? `\"` seems not working.

I never encounter any problems with other **HTML** tags concatenated with the **DTL**.

Comment: You used single quotes and that worked right? What is the problem with that? Also even the first one would work if you run it (Django's parser will simply ignore the outer quotes and its going to replace the content anyway) but given your syntax highlighter has no knowledge of Django it is highlighting things incorrectly.

Comment: VST has knowledge about Django-template syntax, this case is the only one that it does wrong - or maybe there is another reason why it does it this way? So I was wondering, maybe there is some canonical way of doing it that I'm not aware of.

Comment: VS Code doesn't have any builtin knowledge of Django templates. You have to _install_ extensions, etc. if you want syntax highlighting specially for Django otherwise it treats them as normal HTML files. Again as I said both cases you show actually work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/) having single quotes`'` inside the **URL** tag is the most canonic way.

So, this is a proper answer (also evaluated as good by VSC):

[image]